# least residue primitive roots number theory

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $g$ and $h$ be primitive roots of $p$. Fix $a=1,2,3\ldots p-1$.
We know there exist integers $i$ and $j$ such that $g^i\equiv a\pmod{p}$ and $h^j\equiv a\pmod{p}$. Prove that $i\equiv j\pmod{2}$.

Since $g,h$ are primitive roots, so $g^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ and $h^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, and $g^i\equiv a\pmod{p}$ and $h^j\equiv a\pmod{p}$, so $g^i\equiv h^j\equiv a\pmod{p}$. but how to prove $i\equiv j\pmod{2}$? anyone has hint?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We may write $h \equiv g^k \pmod{p}$ for some $k$. Can $k$ be even?

Comment: how could h≡g^k (mod p), in which condition?

Comment: Since $g$ is a primitive root $\pmod{p}$, it has order $p-1$ by definition. Thus $1, g, g^2, \ldots , g^{p-2}$ are all distinct residues $\pmod{p}$ and so form a reduced residue system $\pmod{p}$. (If $g^i \equiv g^j \pmod{p}$ for $1 \leq i<j \leq p-2$ then $g^{j-i} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, contradicting the fact that $g$ is a primitive root.) Thus any non-zero residue may be written as $g^k \pmod{p}$ for some $k$, and in particular $h$ can be written as such.